# Java não conseguiu localizar a classe principal do meu programa

Tags: java

Olá, sou iniciante no java fiz um progaminha bem simples olá Mundo e estou compilando no terminal e quando coloco pra rodar dá erro.

Nome do arquivo ta PrimeiroProgama.java

```
package primeiroprogama;

public class PrimeiroProgama{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.print("Olá World");
    }
}
```

> Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal
>   PrimeiroProgama Causada por: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   primeiroprogama/PrimeiroProgama (wrong name: PrimeiroProgama)

Answer (score 0):

Como você está estudando e aprendendo agora, retire a linha "package" e tente novamente.

Na hora de compilar:

```
java PrimeiroPrograma
```

Comment: É "progama" o dele. Ia comentar pra ele verificar a grafia, mas ele escreveu igual em todas ocorrências, incluso enunciado, então talvez não seja esse o problema.

Comment: Deve ser um modelo chique de nomenclatura relacionando o ingles ao alfabeto grego: `Professional Gamma -> Pro Gama => Progama`